# How to upload an image file using retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am trying to upload an image from android device to server using Retrofit2 and end up getting error '400 Bad Request'. Below is the implementation. Could somebody help to fix the error?

Service :

```
@Multipart
@Headers("Content-type:application/json")
@POST("upload/profile")
Call<JsonObject> changePhotoProfile(@Part MultipartBody.Part partFile);
```

Here is my code :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 100) {
        if (data != null) {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            uploadImageToServer(uri);
        }
    }
}

private void uploadImageToServer(Uri uri) {
    MultipartBody.Part partMap = prepareFilePart("file", uri);
    Call<JsonObject> changeImage = baseServiceAPI.changePhotoProfile(partMap);
    changeImage.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
            
        }
    });
}

private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, Uri uri) {
    File file = FileUtils.getFile(ProfileActivity.this, uri);
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(Objects.requireNonNull(getContentResolver().getType(uri))), file);

    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestBody);
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: see this blog https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/400-bad-request/ and try to find out in which reason you are getting 400.

Comment: the URL is 100% correct, tested successfully in Postman. I have no other way to upload an image file using retrofit2, maybe you can help me to fix the error? @JyotishBiswas

Comment: try without `@Headers("Content-type:application/json")`

Comment: Try removing header and make sure its a valid file. Also you need to parse `MediaType` as `multipart/form-data` instead of resolving file type.

Comment: @JyotishBiswas Yeay, it's work! Thank you for saving my day.

Comment: can i post it as an answer?

Comment: yes, you can @JyotishBiswas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it without `@Headers("Content-type:application/json")`

like

```
@Multipart
@POST("upload/profile")
Call<JsonObject> changePhotoProfile(@Part MultipartBody.Part partFile);
```

it should work